# How to import modules from multiple app in Django shell using relative path?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to load classes of multiple application in Django shell-plus but I receive an error saying it cannot find the module. I would like to tell the shell interpreter to load a module inside my app directory using the relative path. How can I do that? Isn't the shell interpreter supposed to start at the root of the project?

**Shell**

```
from .app1.models import Class1
from .app2.models import Class2

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.app1'; '__main__' is not a package
```

**Files structure**

```
project/
   __init__.py
   settings.py
   app1/
       __init__.py (empty)
       models.py
   app2/
       __init__.py (empty)
       models.py
```

**/project/__init__.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

default_app_config = 'project.app1.apps.App1Config'
```

Comment: What have you got in project.__init__.py?

Comment: @ZF007 content of project/__init__.py is in the question

Answer (score 0):

From command line it should be:

`from app1.models import Class1` # no dots in front off app1 or app2.

`from app2.models import Class2`

In this case at the Django command line you need to be in the project folder for it to work.

If somewhere else:

`from project.app1.models import Class1`

You can test where you are with:

```py
import os

cwd = os.getcwd()

print(cwd)

if cwd == 'any path':
    os.chdir('my_projectpath')

cwd = os.getcwd()

print(cwd)

from app1.models import Class1`
```

Comment: When I remove dot in front of `app1` and `app2` it says `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app1'`

Comment: do you mean everytime I want to use a class I need to import it in `project/__init__.py`?

Comment: PyCharm return an error when I put `from app1.models import Class1` into `project/__init__.py`

Comment: You have to link the path to the classes in in the project/__init__.py. When a you are in settings.py or another script from projects it searches for "class1" first  in the init file. When applied `from app1.models import Class1` it finds it and do whatever you want it to do.

Comment: Sorry.. didn't realize you wanted the loading "manually". My answer is for autoloading.

Comment: Thanks, I'm in `/home/abc/python/project/notebooks` with shell any idea how I could change to ../? I start shell with `python manage.py shell_plus --notebook`

Comment: .. that makes sense it doesn't find the models.py in app1. I've modified the answer with a possible solution where you have to set your own "projectpath" where app1 and app2 are.

Comment: I changed the path as you suggested but now I have `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project'`

Comment: ..removed the cwd from last codeline (no need because you are now in the right directory/folder). Should work now I hope. While helping you I found an issue in one of my setup scripts and showed similar issue... was bit distracted to fix that as well ;-)

Comment: I have to use `import django`, `django.setup()`, then load with `from app1.models import Class1`. I'm afraid your solution doesn't work :)

Comment: Good to read you got it fixed now...  as your question does not include the Django import statements...I therefore explicitly asked "what is in /project/__init__.py" for this reason. As there are zillion possible script/program setups... it could have been in settings.py or prior code from the python command-line via for example anaconda or jupyter notebook.. etc. but conventionally main loading events are done in the main/project __init__.py of a program ;-)